# How can I load multiple excel name sheets as different sql tables in SSIS

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I want to know how to load multiple excel sheets as  tables in SSIS
In such a way that the sheets in an excel file becomes SQL table

Examples an excel file named Customer with sub sheets with names credentials, products and order_ID
They will be loaded to SQL Server as different tables with names dbo.credentials, dbo.products and dbo.order_ID

Thanks

Comment: u can refer https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4157/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-sql-server-integration-services/, for table mapping, you can analysis sheet name and try to use SQL query to execute.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply but that uploaded the sheets into on sql table. What I want is for each sheet to become an sql table according to the names on the excel sheet